# Dissipation in beam-splitter coupled bosonic modes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

Consider two bosonic modes $a,c$ which are coupled by a beam-splitter interaction
$$i\hbar {\gamma_{ac}} [c^{\dagger}a-a^{\dagger}c]$$
Add dissipation $\gamma_c$ for one mode directly to the heisenberg equations (ignoring the associated noise operator)
$$\dot{a} = -i\omega_a a-\gamma_{ac}c$$
$$\dot{c} = -i\omega_cc -\gamma_cc/2+\gamma_{ac}a$$
Then, if we take the limit of very strong damping on the second mode $\gamma_c\to \infty$, so that $c(t)\to 0$, the mode $a$ behaves as though $c$ isn't there at all [footnote 1].
But intuitively, I expect there to be damping of $a$ - shouldn't some probability be transfered into $c$ and then dissipated? Why doesn't the beam splitter interaction allow this?

A more rate-equation-like set of heisenberg equations, of the form
$$\dot{a}=i\omega_aa+\gamma_{ac}c-\gamma_{ac}a$$
$$\dot{c}=i\omega_cc-\gamma_cc+\gamma_{ac}a-\gamma_{ac}c$$
only comes if i manually add non-hermitian dissipation terms to the hamiltonian; an interaction like
$$H_{ac}= \underbrace{-i\hbar ( \gamma_{ca}a^{\dagger}a+\gamma_{ac}c^{\dagger}c)}_{H_{\mathrm{NH}}}+\underbrace{i\hbar ( \gamma_{ac}a^{\dagger}c -\gamma_{ca}c^{\dagger}a) }_{H_{\mathrm{bs}}}$$
Does it make any sense to have an interaction like this?

[footnote 1]
I have solved the system numerically to demonstrate this: these 3 plots are for $\omega_a=1,\omega_c=1,\gamma_ac=1$, and for $\gamma_c=1, 100, 10000$ in that order. Blue is the magnitude $|a|$ and yellow is the magnitude $|c|$. Note how $a$ decays more slowly as we increase the loss for $c$.
[image: gamma_c=1]
[image: gamma_c=100]
[image: gamma_c=10000]